# Ansible > url login check with some test

Tags: ansible

I want to check my application url by ansible. First I want to check url status and after that login with credentials and check some test like some contents after login.
But unable to do it.

```
- name: Check url
  uri:
    url: http://192.168.195.210/app

- name: login check
  uri:
    url: http://192.168.195.210/app
    method: GET
    user: Admin
    password: admin
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 200
```

Let us know is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The uri module can return the body of the call by enabling return_content. Register it to a variable and assert its contents. The first task in the question checks that `/app` returns 200 OK, which does not seem appropriate considering basic auth is required.

```
- name: Ensure wrong credentials are unauthorized
  uri:
    url: http://192.168.195.210/app
    user: Admin
    password: "not the admin password"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    status_code: 401

- name: Ensure admin can log in
  uri:
    url: http://192.168.195.210/app
    user: Admin
    password: "{{vault_admin_password}}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
    return_content: yes
  register: login

- name: Ensure user is properly greeted when logged in
  assert:
    that:
    - "'Welcome Admin' in login.content"
```

Comment: I would just like to suggest not storing plain text passwords and to remind users to use `ansible-vault` or some other encryption method.

Comment: LHSnow it's not working. any username & password shows valid.

Comment: If any credentials are valid, the problem is likely to be on the application side, not with your Ansible playbook. You should probably expect the first uri to return `401 Unauthorized` to fail faster, will edit my answer to reflect that.